# Phrase describing a person's visit to receive food from a food distribution service

Tags: phrase-request, terminology

In an institute that has food distribution service and medical service:

When a person goes to a clinic, we save his details in what we call a "Person's Visit".

But the person also comes once a month to the institute to get food. What is the equivalent term to Visit that can be used for the person's going to get the food ?

I thought of "Person Food give-away", "Person Food Visit", "Person Food Record", but this is not exactly what i'm looking for, is there a more accurate or more convenient term ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps **"Person's Food Recipience"**?

Assuming in the context of your institute that a *visit* always involves medical servicing, perhaps *recipience* could always involve the distribution of food.

In this case, you could just say **"Person's Recipience"** to minimize the length.

"Reception" or perhaps "acquisition" could also work in place of "recipience", but I think "recipience" is best.

Comment: Recipience is a great word! I think in American English [procurement](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/procurement) would be more common.

Comment: @ColleenV It seems to be rare in all varieties of English ([see GloWbE](http://corpus.byu.edu/glowbe/)).  I think the meaning of *recipience* is relatively clear in writing even if you're not familiar with the word, but I'd be wary of using it in speech since it's homophonous with *recipients*, a far more common word.

Comment: @ColleenV I agree with your comment on the OP. Renaming the original label is probably the most streamlined option. Procurement is a far more common word, but I agree with snailboat. :)